# MySQL distinct count

Tags: mysql, distinct

abc table -

```
ID
---
1
2
3
```

xyz table -

```
abc_id | flag 

--------------

1       |   0

1       |   1

2       |   0

3       |   0

3       |   0
```

I need the count of distinct abc_id where if flag = 1 for a particular abc_id, then that id shouldn't be counted. 
In the above example, the count should be 2. Is there any way I can achieve that? Sorry if the question has been answered before or if it's something obvious. Thanks in advance ^^

EDIT: Basically I want the abc_id = 1 to be ignored in the count because one of it's flag = 1. I hope it's clear enough :|

Comment: Please reformat your post. I can't identify anything.

Comment: The count of distinct abc_id for one particular abc_id is always one. Add in the flag and count will be 0 or 1. A count of 2 is impossible according to your textual explanation. Can you try to rephrase your question to remove that ambiguity?

Comment: Edited. My bad. First post.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 3? Or is the first row (abc_id=1; flag=0) ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was figuring out what you meant, but I'm pretty sure it's this. :o)

Count the distinct `abc_id`s, fully excluding the ids that have at least one row that was flagged. So id 1 is excluded, because it has a flag.

You can solve this with a `not in` condition, to exclude all ids that were flagged. After that, you can count the remaining rows, using `count(distinct abc_id)`, to get the number of distinct ids.

```
select
  count(distinct abc_id) as non_flagged_id_count
from
  xyz x1
where
  abd_id not in 
    (select x2.abc_id from xyz x2 where x2.flag = 1)
```

Comment: Yes yes !! That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you sir. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct abc_id)
from xyz as x
left join (
select abc_id from xyz where flag = 1 
) as y using (abc_id)
where y.abc_id is null
;
```